# mapStateToProps must return a plain object. Instead received undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use ternary statement within `mapStateToProps` but it doesn't seem to be updating the state and I keep running into `mapStateToProps must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.` Is this syntax incorrect?

```
const mapStateToProps =  state => {
console.log("current state is:" + JSON.stringify(state.model));
state.model.selectedPerson ?
    {
        selectedCourse: state.model.selectedPerson.selectedCourse,
        startDate: state.model.selectedPerson.startDate,
        courseType: state.model.selectedPerson.courseType,
    } :
    {
        selectedCourse: [],
        startDate: '',
        courseType: '',
    };
};  

const reducers = Object.assign({}, { model: courseReducers });
export { reducers };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
(AddCourseDialog);
```

I'm trying to use a form within a custom modal and the container above is contained within 2 other parent containers. I have not explored using redux form yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in method `mapStateToProps` you should return an object. Change to this

```
const mapStateToProps =  state => {
console.log("current state is:" + JSON.stringify(state.model));
return state.model.selectedPerson ?
    {
        selectedCourse: state.model.selectedPerson.selectedCourse,
        startDate: state.model.selectedPerson.startDate,
        courseType: state.model.selectedPerson.courseType,
    } :
    {
        selectedCourse: [],
        startDate: '',
        courseType: '',
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer said, you just need to return the object. Here's maybe a cleaner way to extract the values and provide defaults using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("current state is:" + JSON.stringify(state.model));
  const {
    selectedPerson: {
      selectedCourse = [],
      startDate = '',
      courseType = ''
    } = {}
  } = state.model;

  return {
    selectedCourse,
    startDate,
    courseType
  };
};
```

Comment: I don't see the error on the console any more but the state isn't getting updated. I don't think the reducer is being called during dispatch. Is there a way to put to console.log statement in the reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i was having the same error. my initial connect method was this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
return {
    post: state.readMore
};
};
const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
// return bindActionCreators(
//     {
//         onTabChange: tabChange,
//         onReadMore: readMore
//     },
//     dispatch
// );
};
export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapActionsToProps
)(ParticularNewsTemplate);
```

i had my bindActionCreators() method commented out(it was commented because i was not passing any values from the *ParticularNewsTemplate* component). but uncommenting the bindActionCreators() method dismissed the error for me. i hope this helps someone.

my final code looks like this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
return {
    post: state.readMore
};
};

const mapActionsToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
return bindActionCreators(
    {
        // onTabChange: tabChange,
        // onReadMore: readMore
    },
    dispatch
);
};

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapActionsToProps
)(ParticularNewsTemplate);
```